# jsTree show edit, delete buttons in right side of each node instead of right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-dnd

In jsTree I want to to show the edit and delete button in right side of each node.
Currently each node shows these button when do right click to node.
Is there any solution as i am new to jsTree

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, http://jsfiddle.net/y8knc8de/, try to replace **a** tag with **button** tag.

```
$('#container').on('ready.jstree', function () {
    $('#container').off('click.jstree', '.jstree-anchor');
});

$('#container').bind('hover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    $('#' + data.node.id + '_my').show();
});

$('#container').bind('dehover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    $('#' + data.node.id + '_my').hide();
});
```